# Why does the TIdMailBox.UnseenMsgs property return 0 value?

Tags: delphi, indy, delphi-xe4

I'm trying to get the number of unread messages of my IMAP mailbox by using `TIdIMAP4` from Indy 10.6.0.4975.

The problem is that the `UnseenMsgs` property returns 0 even when there are some unread messages in the accessed mailbox. This is the code I use:

```
procedure TForm1.FormClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  TotalMsgs: Integer;
  UnseenMsgs: Integer;
begin
  IdIMAP41.Connect(True);
  IdIMAP41.SelectMailBox('Inbox');

  TotalMsgs := IdIMAP41.MailBox.TotalMsgs; // returns correct value
  UnseenMsgs := IdIMAP41.MailBox.UnseenMsgs; // <- returns always 0

  IdIMAP41.Disconnect(False);
end;
```

Why does the `TIdMailBox.UnseenMsgs` property return 0 instead of proper number?

Comment: @TLama: tbat should have been posted as an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @tlama thanks to your correction

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Call the [`StatusMailBox`](http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=%21%21OVERLOADED_StatusMailBox_TIdIMAP4.html) method before you access that property. It is mentioned in the [`UnseenMsgs`](http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=TIdMailBox_UnseenMsgs.html) property documentation as:

> UnseenMsgs is updated when the results from the TIdIMAP4.StatusMailBox
>   method are parsed.

So do it like:

```
IdIMAP41.Connect(True);
IdIMAP41.SelectMailBox('Inbox');
IdIMAP41.StatusMailBox('Inbox', IdIMAP41.MailBox);

UnseenMsgs := IdIMAP41.MailBox.UnseenMsgs;
```

Comment: it works well. i have read the help but i couldn't understand it. thanks.